# Error in Pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
 DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Days NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @Days = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + ltrim(str(datepart(dw,visitdate)))
                        FROM    mktPlanHospitals
                        ORDER BY '],['  + ltrim(str(datepart(dw,visitdate)))
                        FOR XML PATH('')                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DoctorID,datepart(dw,visitdate),DoctorID
    FROM mktPlanHospitals
)t
PIVOT (SUM(DoctorID) FOR datepart(dw,visitdate)
IN ('+@Days+')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

It is giving me error

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't order by a field not specified in your SELECT, if you use the `DISTINCT` keyword. One distinct value could have several values to order it by, thus there could be no correct order.

[Blog entry](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx) about the error.

Comment: I am following the post from http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot. How could i modify to get the resut

Comment: I would remove the YEAR() function in the ORDER BY, I don't think that needs to be there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated the query and getting Incorrect syntax error. Please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working query that solves the problem

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Days NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @Days = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + ltrim(str(datepart(dw,visitdate)))
                        FROM    mktPlanHospitals
                        ORDER BY '],['  + ltrim(str(datepart(dw,visitdate)))
                        FOR XML PATH('')                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DoctorID,datepart(dw,VisitDate) as vdate
    FROM mktPlanHospitals
)t

PIVOT (SUM(DoctorID) FOR vdate
IN ('+@Days+')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE (@query)
```